# Tricky Multiple aggregation In pyspark

Tags: python, join, group-by, pyspark, aggregate

I have a table with three columns:

- product names
- product use case/usage
- user ID

I want to extract for each product, all the use-cases. Then for each of these use-cases, the percentage of users using the product. Here is an example of the data:

```
product-name  use-case     user-ID
A             therapy        X
B             relaxation     X
C             health         Y
A             relaxation     Z
```

1. I want to groupby the product names.
2. Then for each product name I want to groupby the use-cases.
3. Then for each use case (related to a product name) I want to see the percentage of users (i.e. based on their user-IDs). My desired result is to  say that xx% of product A's users are using this product for relaxation...

The output should look like:

[image]

For example, I can say 50% of Product A users are using it for therapy and the other 50% for relaxation.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate in two steps and then join:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df.groupBy(['product-name', 'Use-case'])
   .count()
   .withColumnRenamed('count', 'User counts')
   .join(
       df.groupBy('product-name').count(), 
       ['product-name']
   ).withColumn('User counts', F.col('User counts')/F.col('count'))
   .drop('count').show())

+------------+----------+-----------+
|product-name|  Use-case|User counts|
+------------+----------+-----------+
|           B|Relaxation|        1.0|
|           C|    health|        1.0|
|           A|   therapy|        0.5|
|           A|relaxation|        0.5|
+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to keep the user ID column ? Psidom thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks  @Psidom and  it worked for me I hope it will help others